# What happens when we activate the SharePoint publishing feature?

Tags: publishing-site, publishing

We have created SharePoint site using the team site template.

Does the site become a publishing site template if we activate the publishing feature?

What happens when we activate the publishing feature under:

a)  site feature?

b)  site collection feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Activating the SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure feature adds the Administrative links on the Site Settings page, including the ability to manage Master Pages for both publishing and non-publishing Web sites, Navigation, Searchable columns, Content and Structure, Content and Structure Logs, Variations and Translatable columns.

The publishing feature also includes a publishing approval workflow to help ensure that the information shared is reviewed for quality and correctness.

To enable publishing on a team site go to Site Actions > Site Settings > Site Actions > Manage site features and select Activate SharePoint Server Publishing.

When you look at the feature folder ..\14\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\PublishingSite you can see what is additional functionality is added to your site

For a good overview you can also look at the following post [SharePoint Publishing Features Functionality](http://sharepointchick.com/archive/2011/06/23/sharepoint-publishing-features-functionality.aspx)

Comment: this setting is present under site feature as well as under site collection feature. are they both the same?

Comment: No they are different. One is for the whole site collection the other one is just for the web you are in. You can look at the description of the feature what it does.